# Copy data to a new spreadsheet with specific name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-addons

I was hoping to find a script that does the following:

- Takes data from a particular spreadsheet,
- Duplicates that data to a new sheet as values only
- in the second spreadsheet it creates a new sheet based on the month

A bit more information I am producing monthly reporting which has custom scripts and configures working in the background - however this data is "live" in that it will change based on the current month.

Therefore I either need to print that data to a file per month i.e., each tab gets a month Jan, Feb, March etc or each tab can be set up in the receiving file to pull the data as a snapshot on a particular day via a trigger.

Basically an ImportData snapshot of a target sheet in another Spreadsheet file.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't logged in when I asked this question, but here is the script I am using to achieve this if anyone wants to use it.

```
function CopySheet() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var data = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1").getDataRange().getValues()
var newSh = ss.insertSheet(ss.getSheets()).setName(ss.getSheetByName("sheet1").getRange(4,1).getDisplayValue());
newSh.getRange(1,1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

I found the script somewhere around here or Google forums, so not claiming it. The only modification I made was to grab the value from a cell to name the sheet with, the original script had it naming by date and time - which was no good for me as I would like to be able to reference the new sheet in other reports.